# Does C++ standard guarantee that,using {}/() for initialization will give "0" by default?

Tags: c++, standards, default

Question1:

```
struct S
{
   size_t size;
   int j;
   int k;
   int l;
};

S s={sizeof(S)};
```

Doest C++ standard say，the above {} will initialize "j,k,l" to 0?
Seems it will do, is it part of cpp standard?

Question2:

```
int main()
{
    int* pi=new int[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
        cout<<pi[i]<<',';
    return 0;
}
```

Here the elements in pointer to array(pi) are not initialized, my running result may look like

```
6785200,6782912,0,0,0,
```

But if I change it to

```
int main()
{
    int* pi=new int[5]();//use ()
    for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
        cout<<pi[i]<<',';
    return 0;
}
```

Then, all pi elements are "0". Seems "()" will give elements a "0" value. Is this part of cpp standard?

I also tried to give another value using "()" like this:

```
int* pi=new int[5](7);
```

But it fails compilation. How could I give initialization values to an pointer to array with all elements having same value?

Comment: You really should ask one question per question. Mixing all three of them in one makes it harder to answer, and harder for others searching for answers.

Comment: @SCFrench "Ask one question per question". No, we don't need a billion permutations on initialization rules.

Comment: Sleep tight pupper - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268261

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1

Yes, it is guarantied by [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)
in particular:

> If the number of initializer clauses is **less** than the number of members *[and bases (since C++17)]* or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members *[and bases (since C++17)]* are initialized *[by their default initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14)]* by empty lists, which performs **value-initialization**. If a member of a reference type is one of these remaining members, the program is ill-formed (references cannot be value-initialized).

.

> Question 2

Use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> pi(5, 7);
```

Comment: I think you need to reproduce the rev boxes somehow or tweak the quote a bit. Without the boxes it's hard to tell what the "(since C++1X)" appertains to.

Answer (score 2):

There is a perfect answer to question 1 already, I will answer question 2.

Yes, your observation is correct. Adding `()` after the `new` turns *default initialization* of the elements into *value initialization*. The first form does nothing with created objects (so you observe random numbers), but the value initialization will initialize members - and in this case, will set elements to 0. Unfortunately, there is no way to perform a specific initialization for dynamic int arrays - you can either leave them uninititalized or value-initialize them (to 0).

Using `std::vector` solves this problem.